# How do you insert part of page url inside the brackets of php function?

Tags: php, html, function

I'd like to insert part of the page url where the php function is displayed inside the brackets of the function. For example, my page's url is: [www.mydomain.com/directory/**page*](http://www.mydomain.com/directory/**page*)*

I'd like to take /**page** and insert it inside: function(**here**)

Answer (score 0):

Wont this do?

```php
<?php
$url = "www.mydomain.com/directory/page";
$url = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));
print( $url[count($url)-1]);//prints "page"
//somefunc(page)
?>
```

Split the url by by `/` and select the last part of it. Then you can use it in any function.